# Convert SystemVerilog assertion with delay to invarspec

Tags: delay, formal-verification, model-checking, system-verilog-assertions

I want to convert a SystemVerilog assertion with delay into an invarspec of a formal verifier. The synthesizer gives syntax error for ##1 in the code line below.

```
assert property ( ( req1 == 0 ) ##1( req1 == 1 ) ##1 !( req2 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 0 ) );
```

There are several properties that are to be verified and have delays. I am currently trying to convert them into formal (SMV) model specifications using a synthesizer which works fine for the properties not involving delays. Can I model delay for this formal verifier tool ? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to explicitly model the delayed version of the signals in Verilog, and then you can use an assertion that has no time dependency.

For your example:

```
assert property ( ( req1 == 0 ) ##1( req1 == 1 ) ##1 !( req2 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 0 ) );
```

becomes:

```
reg req1_r,req1_rr;

always @(posedge clk) begin
   req1_rr <= req1_r;
   req1_r <= req1;
end

assert property ( !(( req1_rr == 0 ) && ( req1_r == 1 )) 
               || !( req2 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 0 ) );
```